# React / Stripe / createPortalLink() with firebase v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Stripe extension for Firebase with firebase functions.
Since I refactored a bit my code for firebase v9 modular SDK, I'm getting the following console error with my Stripe createPortalLink() function:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.functions is not a function
    at createPortalLink (Subscription.js:99:1)
```

Here is my function:

```
async function createPortalLink() {
    const functionRef = app
      .functions("europe-west1")
      .httpsCallable("ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink");

    const { data } = await functionRef({
      returnUrl: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard-pro/abonnement/`,
      locale: "auto",
    });
    window.location.assign(data.url);
  }
```

Can anyone please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `getFunctions()` and `httpsCallable()` functions in the new Modular SDK as shown below:

```
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

// after initializing Firebase
const functions = getFunctions();

const functionRef = httpsCallable(functions, 'ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink');

functionRef({
    returnUrl: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard-pro/abonnement/`,
    locale: "auto",
  })
  .then((result) => {
    const data = result.data;
  });
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web-version-9_2) for more details.